# Como criar um gatilho para detectar que uma variável mudou de valor dentro de um laço?

Tags: python

gostaria de saber como eu posso criar um gatilho para rodar uma função somente quando uma variável específica muda de valor dentro de um laço, só que sem precisar definir uma variável fora desse laço, por exemplo:

```
a = 0
a_anterior = 0
for i in range(20):
    if i == 5 or i == 9:
        a += 1

    if a != a_anterior:
        print('a trocou de valor em i =', i)
        a_anterior = a
```

nesse caso eu precisei definir uma variável auxiliar (a_anterior), mas o programa que estou fazendo exige que eu faça isso várias vezes, então eu fico declarando variável auxiliar demais, gostaria de saber como fazer este processo sem precisar declarar nada, agradeço desde já aos senhores.

Comment: Nesse seu caso, tu já pode colocar a função dentro do `if`, até porque a variável `a`, só troca de valor se o `if` for verdadeiro, logo você já tem um gatilho pra uma função.

Comment: Mas seria possível fazer sem ser dentro do if? pois no caso real os valores seriam atualizados por outras funções diferentes, aí não tem como eu fazer isso

Comment: Talvez uma variável global auxiliar lhe ajude, toda vez que algum valor alterar essa variável também alteraria

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 0
a_anterior = 0
for i in range(20):
    if i == 5 or i == 9:
        a += 1

    if a != a_anterior:
        print('a trocou de valor em i =', i)
        a_anterior = a
```

'''testando o codigo com mais casos-teste ele tem funcionado bem,trocando o print pela função que você quer ultilizar ja deve funcionar.'''

Comment: sim, mas a minha dúvida é como fazer um código que faça isso sem que eu precise declarar a variável a_anterior, se for possível

Comment: crie uma lista com a variavel 'a' ai use iteração pra adicionar o valor de 'a' dentro da iteração que já criaste,então crie outra iteração para ver se o valor anterior lista[x] é diferente de lista[x-1].

Comment: Nesse caso eu deveria armazenar todos os valores que a já possuiu na lista? porque no exemplo real o "a" muda de valor centenas de vezes, aí ficaria inviável guardar todos esses valores em uma lista

Comment: Sim,a ideia era armazenar todos os valores de a numa lista.

Comment: Teria algum meio de fazer isso sem armazenar nenhum valor?

Comment: Se existir desconheço.

Comment: Entendo, muito obrigado de toda forma amigo